# retrieve image from MS Access

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to retrieve an image from ms access database for showing in a PictureBox with this code 
my code is like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        myConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Images] where ID=1", myConnection);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["AImage"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                pictureBox.Image = ByteArrayToImage((Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["AImage"]);
            }
        }
        myConnection.Close();   

    }

    Bitmap ByteArrayToImage(byte[] b)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] pData = b;
        ms.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms, false);
        ms.Dispose();
        return bm;
    }
```

but there is an error like:"Parameter is not valid." for `Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms, false);`

I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation for the **Bitmap** constructor: `Bitmap(stream, Boolean)`

> A **System.ArgumentException** is thrown if:
>
> *stream* does not contain image data or is **Nothing**.
>
> -or-
>
> *stream* contains a PNG image file with a single dimension greater than
>   65,535 pixels.

and

> ### Remarks
>
> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap.
>
> Due to a limitation of the GDI+ decoder, an  **System.ArgumentException**
>   is thrown if you construct a bitmap from a .png image file with a
>   single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels.

Have you checked the properties of the image that you are retrieving from the Access database to see if this describes your error situation?